# WheelPickerStyle() in Picker in jumping between old value and new selected value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a parent view and a child view. Parent view calls the child view with a binding which is updated in the child view via a Picker

The relevant variable in parent view is as follows

```
@State private var set = IntervalSet
```

The relevant portion of the child view looks as follows

```
@Binding var set: IntervalSet
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
                Picker("", selection: $set.minutes){
                    ForEach(0..<60, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text("\(i) min").tag(i)
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())

                Picker("", selection:$set.seconds){
                    ForEach(0..<60, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text("\(i) sec").tag(i)
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
        }
    }
```

The issue is that when scrolling through the picker and selecting a value the scroller for a second or two jumps to old value before jumping back to new selected value. How do I stop the scroller jumping back and forth? Thanks

I tried searching on google but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Your code works very well for me in my tests. Maybe your issue is due to some other
 code that you are not showing. Note, I'm on MacOS 14, Xcode 15, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems. If interested I can post my test code.

Comment: Can you please post your test code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test code that works for me:

```
struct IntervalSet {
    var minutes: Int = 0
    var seconds: Int = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var set = IntervalSet()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("minutes: \(set.minutes)")
        Text("seconds: \(set.seconds)")
        ChildView(set: $set)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var set: IntervalSet
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Picker("", selection: $set.minutes){
                ForEach(0..<60, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("\(i) min").tag(i)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
            
            Picker("", selection:$set.seconds){
                ForEach(0..<60, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("\(i) sec").tag(i)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and it seems to be working on my end. I do have multiple layers through which I am passing the bindings. I will try to comment out bunch of stuff and see what else might be causing it.